# How to pass a JavaScript array object to Lasso script and fetch it to a lasso variable?

Tags: javascript, lasso-lang

I am trying to pass javascript array from jquery ajax call to lasso script but while trying to access it in lasso script it returns null records.

I am sure I have missed something in code but unable to figure out what it is.
 Can anybody help me with that. Here are my code snippets.

The ajax request:

```
var url='https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/'+apikey+'/radius.json/'+zip+'/'+radius+'/'+unit;


if(zip.length == 5 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(zip)){
    var zips=new Array();

        $.ajax({
                url:url,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data,function(key,val){
                        $.each(val,function(k,v){
                            zips.push(v.zip_code);
                        });
                    }); 

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'query.lasso',
                        dataType:'json',
                        type:'post',
                        data:{zipcodes:zips},
                        success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                            $.each(data,function(k,v){

                            });

                        }
                    });

                }
        });
    }
```

The lasso query:

```
local(zips=json_decode(web_request->param('zipcodes')))

#zips
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look for web_request -> poststring

Try something like this:

```
local(
    posted      = json_decode(web_request -> poststring) or map,
    zips        = #posted -> find('zipcodes')
)
```

Comment: thanks @jolle for response. but this didn't work out. lasso got froze after sending web request and didn't return anything. 
Am i doing something wrong in sending web request in json format or there is any logical error in it. I am ab to fetch other parameters but the json one.

Comment: Lasso is not sending web requests. It is receiving them. If you have a situation where you're not getting any response, or not the response you expect, you should reduce the Lasso code to a bare minimum. Try as a start to only have web_request -> raw on the receiving page. What does it return?

Comment: it is returning bunch of data as a map. I can see a CONTENT_LENGTH = 125 field. Does is signify anything. The data being sent is this array :
[53183,53187,53186,53188,53702,53072]

Comment: OK, can you confirm that it says REQUEST_METHOD = POST somewhere there? If so, next step would be to put only web_request -> poststring on the receiving Lasso page.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Now I am able fetch json data. Thanks a ton ! :)

Comment: To wrap it up, in my setup the json is always a javascript object and thus translates to a map. Thus json_decode(web_request -> poststring) or map works for me. It's possible that your code returns an array. In that case I suppose you'd need to do json_decode(web_request -> poststring) or array.

Comment: seems like the data i am sending is not in json format thats why  json_decode is not working. It is being sent as an array like this :

zips[]=53183&zips[]=53187&zips[]=53186&zips[]=53188&zips[]=53702&zips[]=53072
so json_decode is unable to decode it.

Comment: Then web_request -> param('zips[]', ',') -> asstring -> split(',') would get you a lasso array. However, I recommend you take a look at my wrp found here; https://gist.github.com/jolle-c/d72c8af689cb7e79ccc1. With it installed you can do wrp('zips[]', -all). That will return staticarray(53183, 53187, 53186, 53188, 53702, 53072)

Comment: This worked finally.Thanks for your prompt response.